# Show that $(f+g)^{-1}((a,b))=\bigcup_{s,t\in \mathbb{R}}f^{-1}((s,t))\cap g^{-1}((a-s,b-t))$

Tags: general-topology, functions

Let $X$ be a toological space. Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are continuous maps $X\to \mathbb{R}$. Define $(f+g)(x)=f(x) + g(x)$. Show that
$$(f+g)^{-1}((a,b))=\bigcup_{s,t\in \mathbb{R}}f^{-1}((s,t))\cap g^{-1}((a-s,b-t))\tag{1}$$
and deduce that $f+g$ is continuous.

**My attempt**: I do not know how to show $(1)$. Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous so $f^{-1}((s,t))\subseteq X$ and $g^{-1}((a-s,b-t))\subseteq X$ are be open. The intersection of them is clearly open, hence $(f+g)^{-1}((a,b))\subseteq X$ is open. This shows that $f+g$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is in the left hand side, we know that $(f+g)(x) \in (a,b)$, so $f(x) + g(x) \in (a,b)$. Then $f(x)$ is some real number, so we can find $s,t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $s < f(x) < t$. So then $x \in f^{-1}[(x,t)]$ by construction. Also $-f(x) > -s, -f(x) < -t$.

But $a < f(x) + g(x)$, so $g(x) > a - f(x) > a - s$.

Also, $f(x) + g(x) < b$ so $g(x) < b - f(x) < b - t$. So from both: $g(x) \in (a-s, b-t)$, so $x \in g^{-1}[(a-s,b-t)]$ and so $x \in f^{-1}[(s,t)\ \cap g^{-1}[(a-s,b-t)]$, so is in the union.

Now if $x$ is in one of those right hand intersections, we know that

$$s < f(x) < t, a-s < g(x) < b-t, \text{ so } (s + (a-s)) < f(x) + g(x) < (t + (b-t))$$

which implies that $x$ is in the left hand side.

Comment: Could you please tell why you wrote $-f(x)>-s$ and $-f(x)<-t$?